# how to using refresh token in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, token, refresh-token

I want to use my refresh token to get a new access token in a react application. I send a request to an API to get data about books. if I get 401 or 500 error I want to send a request to another API with my refresh token to get a new access token to send to first API to get data about books.
here I use 2 useEffect first for getting books data and second to get new access token . also I have a setInterval to run first useEffect which gets books data. If I change access token in localstorage and crash it deliberately to get 401 error manually I want that new access token that comes from refresh token makes access token in localstorage correct again so stop page from crashing.so my problem is 2 things: first I dont know what to do with my new accesstoken . second is When I change accesstoken in localStorage to manually get 401 error , if I refresh the page I want to my localStorage set my new access token so page does not crash.
here is my useContext and my component which handles these two useEffects:

**here is my useContext hook:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
 token: "",
 refreshToken: "",
 isLoggedIn: false,
 login: () => {},
 logout: () => {},
 booksData: [],
  });

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  let initialToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  let initialRefreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh-token");
  const [token, setToken] = useState(initialToken);
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(initialRefreshToken);
  const isUserLoggedIn = !!token;

  const logoutHandler = () => {
   setToken(null);
   localStorage.removeItem("token");
   localStorage.removeItem("books");
   localStorage.removeItem("refresh-token")};

  const loginHandler = (token, refreshToken) => {
   setToken(token);
   setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
   localStorage.setItem("token", token);
   localStorage.setItem("refresh-token", refreshToken);
   };

 const contextValue = {
   token,
   isLoggedIn: isUserLoggedIn,
   refreshToken,
   login: loginHandler,
   logout: logoutHandler,
  };

 return (
   <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
    {props.children}
   </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthContext;
```

**and here is my component:**

```
  const Books = () => {
    const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    const [reqCounter, setReqCounter] = useState(0);
    const [tokenError, setTokenError] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {

     const fetchData = async () => {
       let response = await fetch("some API endpoint", {
       method: "GET",
       headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${ctx.token}`,
        },
  });
  try {
    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {

      setBooks(data.books);
    } else if (response.status === 404) {
      setError("No page found");
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
      setError("You dont have accsess to this page");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    setTokenError(true);
  }
};
fetchData();
}, [ctx.token, reqCounter, ctx]); // Is my dependencies right??

 setInterval(() => {
   setReqCounter(reqCounter + 1);
}, 5000);

 useEffect(() => {
   const refresh = async () => {
   const response = await fetch("some API", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
      refresh_token: ctx.refreshToken,
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  if (response.ok) {
     // Dont Know what should I write here!
  }
};
  refresh();
  }, [tokenError]); // Is my dependencies right??

const content = books.map((item) => (
  <BookItem
    title={item.name}
    year={item.publish_date}
    pages={item.pages}
    author={item.Author}
    img={item.thumbnail}
    key={item.name}
  />
));
return (
  <section className={classes.bookPage}>
    {!error && books.length !== 0 && (
    <ul className={`list ${classes.booksList}`}>{content}</ul>
    )}
    {error && <h2 className={classes.error}>{error}</h2>}
    {isLoading && <PulseLoader color="#f53e3e" className={classes.spinner} />}
  </section>
);
  };

  export default Books;
```

Comment: So what is actually your problem?

Comment: when I refresh my token in second useEffect I dont know what to do with it

Comment: You just have to store it and use it for subsequent API calls. For testing purposes, you can store it in react context, in `sessionStorage` or some variable.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions

Ideally Handle fetch with token and token refresh in one place, something like HttpContext
but to check you can start with existing authcontext

you can refresh token on regular intervals
or when the call in unauthorized

issues:

- when token expires, some call will fail, which needs to be made again with a new token
- When token is refreshed at regular interval, if the old token is invalidated, some call in the queue with older token could fail

pseudo code

```
 in AuthContext 

 const fetchData = async (link) => {
   try {
   let response = await fetch(link, {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
   });
    
   } catch(error) {
      // check status and attempt refresh
      // but existing calls will old token will fail,
      // can will cause multiple refresh token to be called
   }

 }

 //or refresh token on regular interval
   useEffect(() => {

    const timerId = setInterval(() => {

        // refresh token and set token
        // The problems is the moment the token is refreshed, the old token might get invalidated and some calls might fail

    }, tokenRefershTimeInMilliSec)

      return () => {
        clearInterval(timerId)
      }

   }, [])

 ...
 const contextValue = {
   token,
   isLoggedIn: isUserLoggedIn,
   refreshToken,
   login: loginHandler,
   logout: logoutHandler,
   get: fetchData
 }; 

 return <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue} {...props}> // pass all props down
```

or use a http context to seperate concerns

```
const initalValue = // some value
const HttpContext = React.createContext(initalValue);

const initialToken = // from localstorage

const HttpContextProvider = (props) => {

   const [token, setToken] = useState(initialToken)

   const fetchData = async (link) => {
   try {
   let response = await fetch(link, {
   method: "GET",
   headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
   });
    
   } catch(error) {
      // check status and attempt refresh
      // but existing calls will old token will fail,
      // can will cause multiple refresh token to be called
   }

   }

    const value = useMemo(() => {
      return {
       get: fetchData,
       // post, put, delete
    }}, [token]
  
   //refresh token on regular interval
   useEffect(() => {

    const timerId = setInterval(() => {

        // refresh token and set token
        // The problems is the moment the token is refreshed, the old token might get invalidated and some calls might fail

    }, tokenRefershTimeInMilliSec)

      return () => {
        clearInterval(timerId)
      }

   }, [])


   return (<HttpContext.Provider {...props}>)

}
```

if you are open to using axios, then you can check way to auto refresh or use libraries like [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh)

Hope it points you in the right direction